# How to set lifetime for this Iterator trait impl?

Tags: rust

I have these structs

```
pub struct Lexer {
    input: Vec<char>,
    // ...
}

pub struct Token<'a> {
    pub t: TokenType,
    pub literal: Literal<'a>,
}

pub enum Literal<'a> {
    Chars(&'a [char]), // here borrows from the origin input string in Lexer
    // ...
}
```

The field literal of Token with type `Literal` has some slice borrowing directly from origin input string in the `input` field of struct `Lexer`. There is a method of Lexer called `next_token` like this:

```
pub fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token
```

I'm intending to let `Lexer` implement the traitor `Iterator`  like :

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Lexer {
    type Item = Token<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {

        let t = self.next_token();
        Some(t)
    }
```

But get errors like

> the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self
> type, or predicates"

How can I set the correct lifetime and implement Iterator trait for Lexer?

Comment: You can't, the `Iterator` trait doesn't allow borrowing from it's implementor. You should instead have an `IntoIterator` implementation returning a helper struct.